Having npm deprecated issue
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.13.0: Use @eslint/config-array instead
npm warn deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm warn deprecated abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods instead
npm warn deprecated q@1.5.1: You or someone you depend on is using Q, the JavaScript Promise library that gave JavaScript developers strong feelings about promises. They can almost certainly migrate to the native JavaScript promise now. Thank you literally everyone for joining me in this bet against the odds. Be excellent to each other.
npm warn deprecated
npm warn deprecated (For a CapTP with native promises, see @endo/eventual-send and @endo/captp)
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead
npm warn deprecated domexception@2.0.1: Use your platform's native DOMException instead
npm warn deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm warn deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm warn deprecated workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
npm warn deprecated workbox-google-analytics@6.6.0: It is not compatible with newer versions of GA starting with v4, as long as you are using GAv3 it should be ok, but the package is not longer being maintained
npm warn deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

added 1483 packages, and audited 1484 packages in 53s

262 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.

I tried 'npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.' but this didn't work out.

CRA is no longer supported. If you don't want to wade through deprecations and vulnerability warnings, don't use it (try e.g. Vite: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2023/Dec/17/js-tdd-vite.html).
